# replace mongodb value for HTML display

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, mongodb

I am storing numbers as values for a certain field in my mongodb (with mongoose). The reason to store numbers is so that I can do some math on them.

When I get the values back trough an ajax call I would like to display a string instead of the number.

So let's say I  get this JSON object back from the db:

```
[ {id : '1', name: 'john smith', level: '3'},
  {id : '2', name: 'peter miller', level: '2'},
  {id : '3', name: 'susan black', level: '1')]
```

When I display this in a table I want to replace '1' with 'beginner', '2' with 'experienced' and '3' with 'expert'. Ideally I would have a 2nd Object that can store these translations such as
    [ '1' : 'beginner', '2': experienced, '3': 'expert']

I assume I have to iterate over each key/value pair and replace the old value with a new value. Should this be done on the client side (jQuery?) or server side. I am using node.js, express mongodb(mongoose).

Thanks!

Comment: Doing it on the client side should save bandwidth, especially if you download more data than you actually show on screen

Comment: In such cases I'd store the full value into the document in MongoDB directly; but there are space considerations to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such situations you can implement several solution with both advantages and disadvantages:

1. **Doing the mapping on the client side** - **saves bandwidth**, **storage**, **cpu time** and **memory** - in short it saves you money - might add a small delay at the client side
2. **Doing the mapping on the server side** - each time you get something from the database, convert it and send it on the client side as mapped - will cost you heavy in cpu time and memory - application a bit faster on the client side
3. **Saving the data as it in MongoDB** - but will cost you more in storage, memory and bandwith

If you have a small dictionary that needs to be mapped it is a safe bet to move it to the client side and let them do the processing for you.

However if you have a large dictionary that needs to be mapped, maybe storing the data in **MongoDB** might not be that bad.

Based on the use-case extracted from your example I would suggest the first case - move the processing on the client side. Thus your application will be as fast as the client side computations will be and you will end up saving money on your end.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan. Very good points here. I decided to just keep the integers in the db. The advantages as you pointed out are: Keep the mongo document small and simple and reduce CPU load. The dictionary is very simple so why not let the client do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Simon and Roberto,

I decided to go for the client side solution:

```
var replaceValues = $.each(oldValue, function(){
 if (this.level == 1) {
  this.level = 'beginner';
 }
 if (this.level == 2){
  this.level = 'experienced';
 }
 if (this.level == 3){
  this.level = "expert";
 }
});
```